# NSJSONSerialization parse error - unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsjsonserialization, unrecognized-selector

This is the code:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[
            {\"sn\": \"E\", \"t\": \"K\", \"d\": \"Tue 3-Mar\"}, 
            {\"sn\": \"F\", \"t\": \"Y 1\", \"d\": \"Tue 3-Mar\"}
         ]";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *jsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"jsArray: %@", jsArray);

for (id job in jsArray) {
    NSLog(@"job: %@", job);
    NSLog(@"%@", [job sn]);
}
```

In the console, I get this:

```
2014-04-22 15:40:46.464 test[2442:60b] jsArray: (
        {
        d = "Tue 3-Mar";
        sn = E;
        t = K;
    },
        {
        d = "Tue 3-Mar";
        sn = F;
        t = "Y 1";
    }
)
2014-04-22 15:40:46.466 test[2442:60b] job: {
    d = "Tue 3-Mar";
    sn = E;
    t = K;
}
-[__NSCFDictionary sn]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8fa53b0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary sn]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8fa53b0'
```

It seems to recognise the array of objects and the individual object. Why does it object to the property `sn`?

Comment: Use `[job valueforKey:@"sn"]` or job[@"sn"] instead of `[job sn]`

Comment: As rmaddy points out, `sn` is not a method; rather it is a key. Also, if you know what object is being used during array item iteration, declare the object, not `id`. It will help down the road.

Comment: `Why does it object to the property sn` because `sn` is not a property.

Comment: Thanks, all. @Chris - I am a reforming JavaScript guy, and in JS you'd call it a `property` :)  I should use the term `key`, right?

Comment: @Nick, I see. It makes a little confusing since property is also a keyword in Objective-C. Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jsArray` contains dictionaries. So `job` is an `NSDictionary`. `NSDictionary` doesn't have a method named `sn`. If you want the value for the key `@"sn"` then you need:

```
for (NSDictionary *job in jsArray) {
    NSLog(@"job: %@", job);
    NSLog(@"%@", job[@"sn"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `jsArray` contains NSDictionaries, So the type of job will be `NSDictionary`.
You can't retrieve value from `NSDictionary` like that.

Use:

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [job objectForKey:@"sn"]);
```